# kafka how to delete topic with no leader

Tags: apache-kafka

I can't delete / reassign / make any change to topics without leader

> reproduce:
>
> 1. Create a topic with ReplicationFactor=1
> 2. Shutdown the only one broker host
> 3. Use kafka-topic --delete to delete the topic
> 4. Delete process will never end (I waited for more than 6 month, and it starting to get hurt)

describe of topic

```
Topic:topic_73  PartitionCount:1    ReplicationFactor:1
Configs:unclean.leader.election.enable=true
Topic: topic_73 Partition: 0    Leader: -1  Replicas: 755   Isr:
```

broker 755 can never gone back
how can i fix this?

Comment: not fully tested but modify topic metadata from zookeeper manually seems works.

Comment: Would you have some details about which meta should be modified?

Comment: manually delete /brokers/topics/{topic_to_remove}. and restart kafka. again, not fully tested but it gone from the list of topic and you can create a new topic with same name.

Comment: Check out [this post on github](https://github.com/darrenfu/bigdata/issues/6) - or [this article on medium](https://medium.com/@contactsunny/manually-delete-apache-kafka-topics-424c7e016ff3)

Answer (score 4):

You can try this script to clear metadata from zookeeper and directly delete the kafka logs.

`./clear.sh /path-to-kafka-logs sampletopic /path-to-kafka-bin-dir`

clear.sh content is as below:

```
#!/bin/bash
# this script is for the situation that leader is set to -1 and there is no ISR
ZK_HOST=`hostname`
ROOT_DIR=$1
TOPIC=$2
KAFKA_LOG_DIR=$3

# make sure kafka service is stopped while running this
rm -rf ${KAFKA_LOG_DIR}/${TOPIC}*
${ROOT_DIR}/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper ${ZK_HOST}:2181 --topic ${TOPIC} --delete
${ROOT_DIR}/kafka/bin/zookeeper-shell.sh ${ZK_HOST}:2181 rmr /brokers/topics/${TOPIC}
${ROOT_DIR}/kafka/bin/zookeeper-shell.sh ${ZK_HOST}:2181 rmr /admin/delete_topics/${TOPIC}
```

make sure `chmod +x clear.sh` before using it.